# Use of memcpy()

Tags: c++, arrays

How to copy the array elements of type integer to another array using memcpy()?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int arr1[3], arr2[3];
    arr2[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    memcpy(arr1, arr2, sizeof(arr2));
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        cout << arr1[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following for the above code

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

main.cpp:8:23: error: cannot convert ‘’ to ‘int’ in assignment

     arr2[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: The problem is not how to copy the array, but how to initialize one.

Comment: `arr2[3]` corresponds to the content of `arr` at position 3, i.e. an `int`, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get exactly indicates what is wrong with the code. There is nothing wrong with the `memcpy` but rather with the initialization of the array.

When accessing it with `arr2[3]` you request the 4th element in the array (which also does not exist).

Changing to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int arr1[3], arr2[3] = {1, 2, 3}; // Here we initialize the array.
    memcpy(arr1, arr2, sizeof(arr2));
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        cout << arr1[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

yields your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is not to use C-style array and use C++11 `std::array`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::array<int, 3> arr1, arr2{1, 2, 3};

    arr1 = arr2; // and you are done

    for(auto x : arr1) {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5KEKov

clean simple understandable.

`memcpy` is old fashioned `C` code and it is not nice `C++` code. At the end compiler is able optimize all this versions to exactly same execution code, but `std::array` verson is nice to see and maintain.

Note that it also works in the way you are prefer to: https://godbolt.org/z/b9Mn11

Comment: Since C++17, you may even write `auto arr2 = std::array{1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: Yes I know, but it is better not confuse beginner.

Comment: Ok - I was convinced that Almost Always Auto would be more appealing than having to specify template parameters, that's why I mentioned.